# GA data incomplete before 7 AM?

Tags: google-analytics

We have a report using AdCost, impressions, clicks and some other GA data. We have a ETL process that can get these data  scheduled at 4AM every morning. It's been fine all the time until recently we found AdCost, impressions, clicks are much lower than previous days (all normal working days). While the visitors data are correct. I couldn't find why so postpone the ETL to 7AM but still the data is still not correct. If I rerun the same ETL in the morning (9AM) then the data is correct, which proves nothing wrong with the ETL. The only difference is the time to get the GA data. So what has changed?

Note the visitors/sessions are correct (the same at 09 AM as 07AM/04AM), so that's why I am thinking it's something with GA itself.

Comment: Maybe your traffic has increased? "Standard accounts that send more than 200,000 sessions per day to Google Analytics will result in the reports being refreshed only once a day. This can delay updates to reports and metrics for up to two days. " - from here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en, so it seems processing time is related to the number of hits/sessions you send.

Comment: No, the report we use is not a GA report, it is a SSRS report, the report just use the data gathered by the ETL. And it's a small web site with couple of hundred clicks per day so probably not the too much traffic.

Answer (score 0):

GA operates on a delay and it can take up to 48 hours for some reports to be 100% populated with data from sessions.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en-GB